# Image in some pdf not rendered in iOS 12.1

Tags: pdf, ios12

I developed a pdf reader. It's working fine in iOS before iOS 12.1. The image is not rendered in iOS 12.1. Here is the result in iOS 12.1:

[image]

The result in iOS 11:

[image]

I don't know it's a bug or something else. Anybody have the same problem?

Comment: If you share the PDF files in question, people here could check whether there is an issue with the PDF or not.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a bug in iOS 12.1. I have some large PDF files with multiple images. These used to display fine in iOS12 Books app. After the 12.1 update, most of the images do not display correctly in Books (smaller pdfs appear to be okay so far). They also do not display correctly in PDFExpert. However, these display fine when I use Adobe Acrobat app.

Comment: We still currently have the same issue as Jason explained it hereby. Notice that the issue is reproducible with some large PDF files with multiple images which are displayed from a WKWebView (WebKit) OR a PDFView (PDFKit)... I am currently looking for a workaround. I will keep you updated.

Comment: I just created a radar : 47001868. (https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=47001868)

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly a bug since the iOS 12.1 release.

I created a radar on the Apple's Bug Reporter and they told me the following quotes:
[image: Related information from Apple's engineer]

As you can see, **they are currently working on a solution/bug fix**. I really hope it will be fixed in the next iOS release.

**[UPDATE: 02/27/19]**

Almost 2 months later, Apple has closed my ticket. I suppose that the bug fix will be available soon in a next release of iOS & MacOS versions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that PDF rendering bug is fixed in iOS 12.2.